# I'm supposed to create database class of student.I have to create a function which adds courses accounting for addition in attributes of the object

Tags: python-3.x, function, class, self

```
class student:
    def __init__(self, class_student, name, GPA=0,number_of_course=0, number_of_credits=0):
        self.class_student= class_student 
        self.name= name
        self.GPA= GPA
        self.number_of_course=number_of_course
        self.number_of_credits= number_of_credits
    def add_course(self,GPA, number_of_credits):
        return student(self.class_student,self.name, self.GPA,self.number_of_course,self.number_of_credits)


mylad= student('Senior', 'Ardy', 2.7, 0, 0)



print(mylad.add_course(3.2, 3))
```

This code displays <**main**.student object at 0x7ff427458460>.
I am a beginner at Python and do not know how to fix this. If anyone can help me I would appreciate it very much!

Comment: it's because mylad.add_course returns a student object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you are just trying to re-assign a different value the existing `self` attributes of the `Student` class. In this case, you shouldn't use `return` statements, instead re-assign the class attributes themselves.

```py
class Student:

    def __init__(self, class_student, name, GPA=0, num_courses=0, num_credits=0):
        self.class_student = class_student 
        self.name = name
        self.GPA = GPA
        self.num_courses = num_courses
        self.num_credits = num_credits

    def add_course(self, GPA, num_credits):
        self.GPA = GPA
        self.num_credits = num_credits

sample_student = Student('Senior', 'Ardy', 2.7, 0, 0)
sample_student.add_course(3.2, 3)

print(sample_student.GPA)
print(sample_student.num_courses)
...
```

Alternatively, you could elimate the `add_course` classmethod and just do this:

```py
class Student:

    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...

sample_student = Student("Senior", "Ardy", 2.7, 0, 0)
sample_student.GPA = 3.2
sample_student.num_credits = 3
...
```